# BotFramework and Messenger Extension (address from psid and waterfall)

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

We followed this tutorial and got the postback working. Receive the psid
https://blog.messengerdevelopers.com/using-the-webview-to-create-richer-bot-to-user-interactions-ed8a789523c6

In the webview, users are to select some township codes.

In postback, i got the township codes and psid.
In the postback function, there is no session object. So how can we get "address" from psid and also we need to get back to the waterfall (say 4th question) with this answer. The township question is say 3rd question in the 5 question series.

Thanks

Comment: Hey there, I'm the author of that post. Ok, got it.  

You need to make sure you also add the app id to _public/options.html_:  

    MessengerExtensions.getContext('<YOUR_APP_ID>',  

I will get the post updated to explicitly mention that, I just tested the tutorial example and it works, but it looks like you made your own changes, which is great, but if that doesn't help fix your issues, I'll need a bit more detail to help.